# Is Gestational diebetes common to all pregnant women? Can the unborn develop complications from mother with Gestational Diabetes?

Tags: diabetes, type-1-diabetes, obstetrics

I work as an Industrial Training student in a government Hospital and every Tuesday, happens to be our Immunization clinic. Then a Health talk proceeds.

During the Health talk which was conducted by my Mother. She is a Public Health Nurse. While giving a health talk to the mothers, she asked if they were ever diagnosed of Gestational Diabetes, and every single mother present(Nurses, Breastfeeding mothers and a few that came for ante-natal) all said they had been diagnosed of Gestational Diabetes. They signified by raising their hands.

It makes me ponder if Gestational Diabetes is heriditary or if its a common occurence for pregnant women. Do all Pregnant women experience it or only a few cases of probably 10% dont?

That being said, could it be responsible for Childhood Diabetes, that is, Juvenile Diabetes(Type 1)?

or

If not being responsible, could it be a contributing factor?

What other complications could there be for the unborn child?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Your questions, including the statistics and complications in children, have clear answers in various online articles, like https://www.cdc.gov/diabetes/basics/gestational.html

Comment: @Jan Thank you for the link.